# Is this joint between the foundation and first row of mortar typical

Tags: concrete, foundation, brick, masonry, mortar

Just wondering if this is a normal appearance for the area where the foundation and first row of mortar/brick meet. There are no signs of any structural cracks or anything like that in the area. Is this just cosmetic or should there be some sort of sealing done?

[image]

Comment: It looks normal. Are you having problems with moisture inside? The slight crack could be filled with concrete sealant but nothing here looks serious.

Comment: No moisture problems that I can detect. 
Thanks for your input. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

The bricks are attached to the foundation with a layer of mortar. This is not only normal but just about the only way to do it. Are there any other concerns it is hard to craft an answer when things look normal and no specific question. Are you concerned where the forms meet? The slight indent in the foundation?

Comment: Thanks for the response. No other concerns. Just wanted to make sure this was normal and  I wasn’t overlooking something that needed addressed.

Comment: Ed, you think that shrinkage crack between the mortar and the top of the concrete wall is normal?

Comment: I was thinking it was more just how the builders applied the mortar than a shrinkage crack.